# Reading shapefile faster using Python basemap (and pickle)

Tags: performance, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to plot a simple 'merc' map with boundary from shapefile. The total size of the shapefile ne_10m_admin_0_countries_lakes.shp is just 8mb. The simple mslp surface plot from GFS data took about more than 28 sec which I think is too much. After investigation I found that it is the reading of shapefile consuming around 10 sec. A simple code to demonstrate the issue is shown below:-

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap


south = 0
north = 5
west = 70
east = 85

m = Basemap(projection='merc', llcrnrlat=south, urcrnrlat=north,
        llcrnrlon=west, urcrnrlon=east, resolution='c')
m.readshapefile('data/gis-data/world_countries/'
    'ne_10m_admin_0_countries_lakes', 'ne_10m_admin_0_countries_lakes', linewidth=0.7)

plt.savefig('map.png')
```

To show the problem I am facing, I have run the above code with and without commenting the path to shapefile. Here is time the script took after reading from shapefile:-

```
$ time python test.py 
real    0m18.234s
user    0m17.832s
sys 0m1.020s
```

Here is the result without reading from shapefile:-

```
$ time python test.py 
real    0m2.506s
user    0m2.360s
sys 0m0.324s
```

I hear that pickle is one of the most suitable solution. But I could not find any of the code with respect to reading shapefile.

Comment: I don't really know about pickle for dump and load shapefile but it won't remove the fact that you have to open your 8Mo shapefile at least once with a python method (pickle will serialize a python object). I don't know if the map you're exporting needs a great level of details, but if not I would suggest you to make a generalized version to use with Basemap (you can simplify your layer with python modules such as `shapely`, or use your fav. desktop GIS application, or use some web-service like [MapShaper](http://www.mapshaper.org) ).

Comment: You are correct. The pickling of Basemap instance works absolutely fine and it reduces a great amount of time. I also agree that I have to read shapefile at least once. I have little idea about to make it faster.

Comment: Do you need the shapefile at all? As long as the basemap instance `resolution` param is not None then basemap is actually loading its own coastlines. Most of the time spent initialising the basemap object is spent doing just that.

Comment: Yes it is absolutely required. There are some places where Basemap does not have state boundaries which I need to show on the map.

Comment: Might be useful then: http://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html#mpl_toolkits.basemap.Basemap.drawcounties

Comment: Cross-posted as http://stackoverflow.com/q/35275897/820534

Comment: Does the shapefile have a lot of attributes? If so change the filename of the .dbf file next to the .shp file (or delete it)